# Android: Why is it not advisable to pass data to fragments directly using the fragment object?

Tags: android

Until this point, I was passing data to fragments using bundles. I need to know why it's not common to see code as

```
MyFragment frag=new MyFragment();
frag.passData(myList);
ft.replace(R.id.container, frag).commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to send data like following

```
MyFragment frag=new MyFragment();
frag.passData(myList);
```

The reason is if the fragment is going to be destroyed and created again due to memory leakage by Android then all your data is lost and can't be recreated again.

If you will send data like following

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("list", myList);
MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
frag.setArguments(args);
```

In case of any memory leakage or when activity is recreated, Bundle will be marshaled and its byte[] will be persisted until it is created again, and then the Bundle will be created by unmarshalling the saved byte[]. so a NEW object will be created for Fragment. So data is not lost in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I felt we can get a good reference to the previous fragment through my method, it seems harder with using bundles